# Regex: Select first character then rest between tags

Tags: html, regex

Im looking to scrape some html and output with colors

```
<name>Whatever</name>
```

to be scraped and output like this:

```
[color=green]W[/color][color=purple]hatever[/color]
```

I have accomplished selecting just first and second character with desired color tags however it only gives first and second character like I mentioned using this:

```
<name>[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*</name>
```

I have tinkered a bit with no success, any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Edit: More info

Here is the code.  Its read with python dunno exactly what u would call this tho

```
skill=videoTitle
skill=allowDuplicates
item_infos=<name>[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*</name>
item_order=first|rest
item_skill=rss

item_info_name=title
item_info_from=[COLOR=green]' + first + '[/COLOR][COLOR=purple]' + rest + ' [/COLOR]
item_info_build=%s`
```

Edit: Another bump in the road:

Got it working with Fedes answer of:
`<name>(.)(.*?)<\/name>`

Now Im looking do omit empty feilds.  When they are empty like  the display the other empty feilds after  as the title.  Thanks for all the help here folks :)

Comment: Can you post your actual regex? Is it safe to assume you're using JavaScript?

Comment: It's also worth noting that you should just use regex to match the content of a tag and not HTML itself.

Comment: Ill ad that info to top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's well known that you shouldn't parse xhtml with regex since you can mess up things for unicode characters.

In case you want to use regex anyway, you can use a regex like this:

```
<name>(.)(.*?)<\/name>
```

With a replacement string as this:

```
[color=green]$1[/color][color=purple]$2[/color]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC6vJ1/1)**

On the other hand, if you want to do it for all tags, you could use something like this:

```
<(.*?)>(.)(.*?)<\/\1>
```

Replacement string:

```
[color=green]$2[/color][color=purple]$3[/color]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC6vJ1/2)**

Comment: Your first method worked Fede Thanks so much.  1 more question if u can.  What about omitting empty tags for example if a file has `<name></name>` lines with that output a bunch of tags surrounding it I would prefer them to be skipped.  I recently discovered this `([^>/][^>]*)` which works if im scraping it all but in sections it doesnt fit

Comment: @BobbyPeters this is why regex is not the right choice for parsing html. It messes up when you have inner tags. Regex is just a matching tool by pattern but if you need logic you have to use a html parser.